# Magmi: On the fly category creator/importer root catalog

Tags: multistore, category, magmi, csv

We are using a multistore deployment. In the csv we have as follows:

(mind you these are not literal, just examples)

**store:** using the store code for the store view, e.g.: **substore1_en**
**websites**: using the same as store: **substore1_en**
**categories:** [Root Category for Sub Store 1]/category 1/subcategory 2

We are getting an error returned by magmi:
`Cannot find site root with names : Root Category for Sub Store 1`

We've read the documentation and are quite certain everything was set up correctly. Anyone have any idea why magmi can't seem to find the root catalog specified?

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem with our multistores and different categroy structures but the same products (partially). What we did was import the category with the most products first, then update with less detail by adding categories.

Here's how, i quoted from the magmi wiki:

In case of a multiple store with multiple import runs, one can experience, that the latest run overwrites the earlier settings of categoryID.

To avoid this, you insert a new column "category_reset" and give all rows the value 1 for the first run (setting also the admin values) and the value 0 for following runs. Also set „using mode“ to „create new items & update existing ones“ for the first run and "Update exisiting items" for the following before you "Run Import".

Answer (score -1):

you have to add a colum _root_category to add Root categories

Comment: Please could you give a bit more of a detailed answer. This will be useful when someone is evaluating if it is a working solution.